# Defining a new bracket style

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros

In order to prepare my math notes in LaTeX I need to combine two existing symbols, `\langle` (or `\rangle`) with a vertical bar.

Temporarily I am using a command invented by myself: `\newcommand{\disk}[2]{\mathrel{\langle\mkern-3.85mu\mid\mkern-4mu} {#1} \mathrel{\mkern-4mu\mid\mkern-3.85mu\rangle}_{#2}}`, but the results don't satisfy me. I want to use it as a pair of brackets, unfortunately spacing is poor: `\[\mu(\disk{a}{n}) = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} \mu (\disk{a + kp^n}{n+1})\]` compiles to

[image]

As I suspect, there must be a TeX command to define custom brackets. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is  a `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command in `mathtools` package -- you should use that one, I think -- but from a personal point of view: Your 'brackets' do not really look nice, like squeezed triangles

Comment: Just curious: what is the advantage of this notation over using a good-old-fashioned function, like `f_n(a)`, `f_{n+1}(a+kp^n)`?

Comment: @Matsmath here `\langle a \rangle_n` denotes the set `a + p^n \Z_p` and `\mu` is some unknown function whose properties I investigate.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I have also tried using `\triangleleft` as a delimiter, but it does not scale vertically well.

Comment: The problem with that delimiter is that it is not easily extensible, if you want it on a fractional term.  If you don't need it extensible, I would use `\triangleleft` and `\trangleright` and use `\scalebox{.5}[1]` to compress it (numbers may vary).

Comment: Incidentally, see page 5 of the `scalerel` documentation (ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/scalerel/scalerel.pdf) to see something like this in action, with stretchability.  It is not very pretty.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is perfectly valid syntax see section 2.1.3 »Bindings and schema types« of [The Z Notation: A Reference Manual](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse503/00sp/zrm.pdf) (PDF page 36).

Comment: @HenriMenke: I did not say that it is not valid, did I? I just said that it does not look nice in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I use `scalerel` to scale the symbols, I only scale them to the size of `[` and `]`, rather than with arbitrary stretch.  Here, I just use `\triangleleft` and `\triangleright` as the base shapes.

EDITED to use `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`, instead of `\mathinner`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\newcommand\langlebar{\mathopen{\scalerel*[.55ex]{\triangleleft\mkern3mu}{[}}}
\newcommand\ranglebar{\mathclose{\scalerel*[.55ex]{\mkern3mu\triangleright}{]}}}
\begin{document}
\[\mu(\langlebar a\ranglebar_n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} \mu (
  \langlebar a + kp^n\ranglebar_{n+1})\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\mathinner`?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I wasn't sure what was appropriate, so I looked at Knuth's TeXbook, where he says that `\mathinner` is used for `\left` `\right` symbols, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: OP want's to use the brackets like they were actual brackets, i.e. `\left\langlebar ... \right\ranglebar`.  Also, the second argument of `\disk` should appear as index.

Comment: No, I’d go for `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`, here.  But, of course, the “right” answer is Henri Menke’s.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti  Thanks.  Revised for that, though I needed extra `\mkern`.  I agree Henri's answer is "right".

Answer (score 8):

The `MnSymbol` package has your desired symbols as `\langlebar` and `\ranglebar`.  They also work with `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\[\mu(\langlebar a \ranglebar_{n}) = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} \mu (\langlebar a + kp^n \ranglebar_{n+1})\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see it also changes other symbols.  If you don't want to use the entire `MnSymbol` package but only these brackets, you have to include the relevant parts in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE10
  <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSymbol}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSymbol}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\langlebar}{\mathopen}{MnSymbol}{'152}{MnSymbol}{'152}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\ranglebar}{\mathclose}{MnSymbol}{'157}{MnSymbol}{'157}
\begin{document}
\[\mu(\langlebar a \ranglebar_{n}) = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} \mu (\langlebar a + kp^n \ranglebar_{n+1})\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In `unicode-math` such a symbol is available but not in every font.  We have to load it using the `range` option from, e.g., `XITS Math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\llangle,\rrangle}]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
\[\mu(\llangle a \rrangle_{n}) = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} \mu (\llangle a + kp^n \rrangle_{n+1})\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a comment about the naming of these brackets in the xits/stix fonts:  somehow the fact was overlooked that the names `\llangle` and `\rrangle` had been used earlier in the st mary road fonts for doubled angle brackets, and that assignment should have had priority.  there may be an attempt to rectify this unfortunate situation, but there are other ramifications that need to be researched first.  just a friendly warning.