# Special brackets symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, brackets

Can't find any way to correctly write these two special brackets without having spacing between the symbols that compose them.

[image]

[image]

Apparently no package is found by Detexify

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and, for one case, and this, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324173/defining-a-new-bracket-style, for the other

Comment: Perfect. It was exactly what I was looking for. thx.

Answer (score 3):

The XITS font has your desired symbols.  You can easily load it using `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\llangle,\rrangle,\lBrace,\rBrace}]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\llangle \rho \rrangle$

$\lBrace \varphi \rBrace$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You should probably "move" your answer -- or ask the moderators to do it for you... -- to one of the older queries. (I would suggest http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100966/5001.) You may also want to highlight more explicitly that this approach requires LuaLaTeX and/or XeLaTeX.